Offline Paper Wallet Creation
I was wanting create an offline Paper Wallet, ideally, without using a computer for nothing more that verification.
So, that's how I came across Entropy.
What is the risk of attempting to create a wallet using non-computer methods only? I read some about people creating wallets that already had coins in them. The solution to getting around this is to ensure have a certain amount of entropy when you generate it.
Some say rolling dice will get you enough, but I'm not certain.
Does anyone know of any different methods?
Are there not any rng mechanisms you can pair with some math or something to achieve the threshold entropy for key generation?
Am I even understanding all this right, lol?
Are there human ways to get computer levels of entropy that are simple and straightforward? While it probably isn't something I will need all the time, it's very important i have at least one wallet that I generated myself, offline, that only me and god know about.
Ideally, I would want a method that is simple and that I could personalize over time.
For instance, if I could take a phone that couldn't connect to the Internet, Using the sensor data over a period of time to generate the key. Something kinda like that but lol not with the phone. Like those generators that you move your mouse around to do the rng. But with a few more added layers.
Any help is appreciated.
